# JSP - How to use an image, sent from a servlet, amongst the HTML a JSP page?

Tags: java, html, image, jsp, servlets

I have this code:

```
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);

            response.setContentType("image/jpeg");

            response.setContentLength(bytes.length);

            response.getOutputStream().write(bytes);
```

When it runs the page that comes up is just a blank webpage with the image on top. How do I send this image to the JSP to use amongst the HTML?

Comment: why cant you sent the image link.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the src tag to point to the servlet's url as in
`<img src="/servlet/url/here"></img>`.

Comment: Thank you. I should of thought of that but at least now I know!